# Rotating all features by a single other feature's azimuth

Tags: azimuth, fme-form

I have a set of CAD drawings all published neatly squared to a page, but not located or rotated to true north. One of the drawings contains some referencing that I can extract and use to then apply to the rest of the feature sets.

Short of using pen and paper to write the results of an AzimuthCalculator value and then input that into a Rotator, how can I plug that output into the input?

Answer (score 0):

Use the little-known TextPropertyExtractor transformer. That will fetch info from the text containing the referencing info.

Assuming you can parse that info (for a first suggestion, use a StringSearcher or SubstringExtractor transformer to do that) then you can feed those values into a Rotator and maybe an Offsetter transformer.